# React-Admin RichTextInput with TipTap with Image extension not working

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, tiptap

I want to insert  on my RichTextInput component on React-Admin, but that is not working.
Even the example on the docs about using HorizontalRules are not working too. The button doesn't work, and by default ra-input-rich-text already have HorizontalRules extension, it works if I input "---" on the text.

What I want exactly is put the image url with a button on my toolbar and it would be inserted where my cursor is on the editor. But even manually putting the tag (as `<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/8xznAGy4HcY/800x400" />`), the image is not rendered.

This is my current RichTextInput component:

```
import {
    DefaultEditorOptions,
    RichTextInput,
    RichTextInputToolbar,
    LevelSelect,
    FormatButtons,
    AlignmentButtons,
    ListButtons,
    LinkButtons,
    QuoteButtons,
    ClearButtons
} from 'ra-input-rich-text';
import { ToggleButton } from '@mui/material';
import { useEditor } from '@tiptap/react'
import Image from '@tiptap/extension-image'
import Remove from '@mui/icons-material/Remove';

import { Box } from '@mui/material';

export const MyRichTextInput = ({ size, ...props }) => {
    const editor = useEditor(MyEditorOptions)
    return (
        <RichTextInput
            editorOptions={MyEditorOptions}
            toolbar={
                <RichTextInputToolbar>
                    <Box sx={{
                        display: 'flex',
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        flexWrap: 'wrap',
                    }} >
                        <LevelSelect size={size} />
                        <FormatButtons size={size} />
                        <AlignmentButtons size={size} />
                        <ListButtons size={size} />
                        <LinkButtons size={size} />
                        <QuoteButtons size={size} />
                        <ClearButtons size={size} />
                    </Box>
                    <ToggleButton
                    value="Image"
                    aria-label="Add an image"
                    title="Add an image"
                    onClick={() => editor.chain().focus().setImage({ src: url }).run()}
                    selected={editor && editor.isActive('image')}
                >
                    <Remove fontSize="inherit" />
                </ToggleButton>
                </RichTextInputToolbar>
            }
            label="Body"
            source="body"
            {...props}
        />
    )
}

export const MyEditorOptions = {
    ...DefaultEditorOptions,
    extensions: [
        ...DefaultEditorOptions.extensions,
        Image
        
    ],
};
```

What I need to put an image and this be rendered here and in the "RichTextField"? And how to create a button to ask me the url and insert the image on the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They updated React Admin (I was using 4.15) to 4.20 and now it supports Image and horizontal line.
And now the toolbar is responsive.

Mor info in the issue: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/7806

Answer (score 0):

Tiptap edits input by manipulating the `editor` object held by the target `RichTextInput` component.
You can access the `editor` object in the context of the target `RichTextInput` component by using `useTiptapEditor()`.
So you need to create another button or toolbar component and then load it.

MyImageButton component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useTranslate } from 'ra-core';
import { useTiptapEditor } from 'ra-input-rich-text';
import { ToggleButton } from '@mui/material';
import ImageIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Image';

export const MyImageButton = (props) => {
    const translate = useTranslate();
    const editor = useTiptapEditor();

    const label = translate('ra.tiptap.image', { _: 'Image' });

    const addImage = React.useCallback(() => {
        const url = window.prompt(
            translate('ra.tiptap.image_dialog', { _: 'Image URL' })
        );

        if (url) {
            editor.chain().focus().setImage({ src: url }).run();
        }
    }, [editor, translate]);

    return editor ? (
        <ToggleButton
            aria-label={label}
            title={label}
            {...props}
            disabled={!editor?.isEditable}
            value="image"
            onClick={addImage}
        >
            <ImageIcon fontSize="inherit" />
        </ToggleButton>
    ) : null;
};
```

then load it in `RichTextInput`

```
import {
    DefaultEditorOptions,
    RichTextInput,
    RichTextInputToolbar,
    LevelSelect,
    FormatButtons,
    AlignmentButtons,
    ListButtons,
    LinkButtons,
    QuoteButtons,
    ClearButtons,
} from 'ra-input-rich-text';
import HorizontalRule from '@tiptap/extension-horizontal-rule';
import Image from '@tiptap/extension-image'
import { MyImageButton } from './CustomEditorInputImageButton';

export const MyRichTextInput = ({ size, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <RichTextInput
            toolbar={
                <RichTextInputToolbar>
                    <LevelSelect size={size} />
                    <FormatButtons size={size} />
                    <AlignmentButtons size={size} />
                    <ListButtons size={size} />
                    <LinkButtons size={size} />
                    <QuoteButtons size={size} />
                    <ClearButtons size={size} />
                    <MyImageButton />
                </RichTextInputToolbar>
            }
            label="Body"
            source="body"
            {...props}
        />
    );
}

export const MyEditorOptions = {
    ...DefaultEditorOptions,
    extensions: [
        ...DefaultEditorOptions.extensions,
        Image,
        HorizontalRule,
    ],
};
```